# Rails: Allow user to retrieve my Google Calendar events

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, calendar, google-calendar-api

I am ultimately trying to allow a User to schedule an appointment inside of my Google Calendar from a Rails application I built. First, I will need to retrieve a list of already taken Google Calendar events. I only know how to allow the User to access their Google Calendar events through Oauth2.0, but is there a way to allow every user to have access to mine?

I am not asking for any code, as much as I am asking for direction and clarification regarding this issue, thank you.

Comment: In order to use the Google API any user has to go through an oauth flow.